# Need to run a cron job on Google compute engine (gce) to execute a gcloud snapshot with service account

Tags: cron, backup, gcloud

I've been successful at creating and executing a snapshot script if I use gcloud auth to use my personal account. but if I have the cron run as root or as a selected user nothing happens during the cron.

I used this script https://gist.github.com/peihsinsu/73cb7e28780b137c2bcd and it works great and as the author notes: "Install gcloud and auth first" are required.

My problem is in using my personal account and not the service account.

When you execute gcloud auth login you get a very important message

Your credentials may be visible to others with access to this
virtual machine. Are you sure you want to authenticate with
your personal account?

Any thoughts or suggestions to avoid this security risk.

Comment: Solved the problem! turns out that the gcloud sdk path was not available to cron user because it does not load the bash script. The simple solution was to add the PATH environment to my cron right above the cron task

Comment: gcloud does not install globally in /usr/bin by default and installs to your local directories. So the path is only added to your own bash script.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. In fact, the path of pre-installed gcloud command which comes with a GCE VM instance is: /usr/local/bin/gcloud

Comment: @DrakeZabriskie I can see from your comments that you have resolved this issue can you post your solution as an answer, which will help other users with the similar issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Took some time to figure it out. The script is valid. The tricky part is the user permissions. There are 2 user types - the OS user and the GCE user.

The gcloud uses the GCE user, which is most likely something like blabla@gmail.com. You need to figure out what is the OS user that can use GCE credentials. In my particular case (i've set up VM instance using Bitnami) the user was bitnami (NOT root!!!).

You need to make sure that:

- you set up the default gcloud user your GCE user (gcloud config set account blabla@gmail.com)
- your script file is executable (chmod +x)
- your script file's owner is the user that has GCE credentials
- you set up cron for the particular user (in my case sudo -u bitnami crontab -e)
- you include full path to the script inside crontab